# Angular 2 - open a window with an Angular app structure

Tags: angular, window, angular4-router

I'm developing an Angular 2 app. In my main page I need a button that opens a new window (NOT a TAB / the window should be moved on a tablet connected with the PC). The two windows (the main one and the generated one) need to comunicate via postMessage/signalR library.

I basically created a button component and I bound a function that calls `window.open('mycustomurl','_blank', 'etc..')`, then I moved to the tablet. But now I specifically need an Angular structure (components, services, ..) in this new window.

How can I accomplish that? I tried 1) Angular Router, 2) building two different app in a single project (two index, two main, etc..), both with zero results.

Comment: Please clarify this statement: "the window should be moved on a tablet connected with the PC". Not sure I get what you are trying to do. I understand you have a button that you want to popup a window, but what does that have to do with communicating between a pc and a tablet?

Comment: Sure. I've got a tablet connected with the PC and used as a second screen. The Angular app on the main window is basically a "PDF pre-viewer"; when a single file is selected in a list, and the button is clicked, it opens the PDFJS viewer in a new window. Then the window is moved to the tablet using the standard JS command ( moveTo(), resize() ).

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot more sense now. Perhaps add that to the question so its more clear to someone reading it? Lastly, you said you have tried a couple of approaches, but what exactly didn't work? Be as specific as you can with the issue so we can help.